# Issues with Linux 5.15.0-50-generic Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, kubuntu, 22.04

I cannot boot up using `5.15.0-50-generic` kernel. I can boot up using the previous kernel `5.15.0.48-generic`.

I have tried reinstalling Nvidia drivers but it is still not working. I was wondering if anyone else has this issue.

I have HP OMEN
[image]
[image: error message]

***Update***

I remove `5.15.0-50-generic` kernel and run `sudo update-grub`
reboot my computer and it boot using kernel `5.15.0.48-generic`

I reinstalled the `5.15.0-50-generic` kernel and updated my grub. This is the error message I get below:

[image]

Also, my grub keeps booting up before my Kubuntu OS:
[image]

Comment: From a working kernel you might need to regenerate a new initramfs for that kernel.  `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.15.0-50-generic`

Comment: Yes I am having the same issue `linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic` boots but `50` and `52` do not.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1993004 (I using  515.65.01 nvidia drivers)

Comment: @Terrance it did not work. I still get the error message when booting into 5.15.0-50 kernel

Comment: You might have to remove the kernel and possibly reinstall it.  But generally when it is unable to mount like you have showing there, that is that the initramfs is messed up.  Maybe you have to remove the one first, then regenerate a new one.  `sudo update-initramfs -d -k 5.15.0-50-generic` then try to build a new one with the same command I put in above.  Other than that, I believe you are looking a possibly reinstalling the 50 kernel.  However, 52 just came out, so you can try updating from a working kernel again.

Comment: After creating a new initramfs, try updating grub again before rebooting.  `sudo update-grub` just to make sure that the kernel still updated OK.

Comment: should I update the grub after removing 50 kernel then reinstall it? @Terrance

Comment: Actually, yes.  After rebuilding the initramfs, or reinstalling a kernel, the `sudo update-grub` should be run before rebooting.

Comment: @Terrance I have updated the question. it is still not working for me

Comment: Also this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/y0c1k9/cant_boot_on_515050generic_and_nvidia_driver/

Comment: I managed to get it to boot using the update-initramfs command but now its missing nvidia drivers

Comment: Do you know how to get the grub stop booting up?

Comment: For NVIDIA they should be installed from the repos, as installing them from NVIDIA themselves can cause boot problems, etc.  `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510`.  Plus, installing the NVIDIA drivers this way they will carry over into new kernel updates and upgrades.

Comment: Please, press " This bug affects X person. Does this bug affect you? Edit "

I have created bugreport. But no feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had what looks like the same issue with `5.15.0-50-generic` and `5.15.0-52-generic` and tried various things. In the end I got `5.15.0-52-generic` booting with the nvidia drivers working correctly by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove '*nvidia*'
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

See [this lunchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1992679) for details.

Comment: How do I install 52 kernel? 'sudo apt update and up' does not offer the upgrade

Comment: Strange that its not there for you, you can install using this command: `sudo apt install linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic`. I would also expect my fixes to work fine for `5.15.0-50-generic`. Its possible that our issues are not quite the same though I guess.

Comment: it didn't work for me. So what I did was I perform fresh install Kubuntu 21.10 and upgraded to 22.04 with `Linux 5.15.0-52-generic`. it working now but I do not have Nvidia drivers install onto my computer. if I install it, it wont boot up. I just get black screen.

Comment: @krillavilla  Good thing you upgraded because Kubuntu 21.10 is EOL.  That is probably why you were not upgrading your kernel to .52 and also why you were having install issues as well.  You had marked 22.04 in your question and title so we had no idea that you were using an EOL distribution.  Please when you ask details be as precise as you can be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue. I found solution:
Just disable internal videocard (Intel HD in my case) in BIOS (UEFI) at all.

My bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/linux/+bug/1992679

Solution:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/linux/+bug/1992679/comments/52

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and switch primary video to PCI Express in UEFI and it worked.

Many Thanks.